# java capturing webcam images macbook

Tags: java, macos, exception, webcam, javacv

I'm currently beginning on a project where I want to capture and manipulate a datastream from my webcam in order to start I wanted to take some pictures from my webcam and show those to the user. However this gave an error.

```
public class quicktest  implements Runnable {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Thread t=new Thread(new quicktest());
            t.start();
        }

        IplImage image;
        CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Web Cam");
        public quicktest() {
            canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0); 

            int i=0;
            try {
                grabber.start();
                IplImage img;
                while (true) {
                    img = grabber.grab();
                    if (img != null) {
                        cvFlip(img, img, 1);// l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
                        // show image on window
                        canvas.showImage(img);
                    }
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
```

this gives the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnivideoInputLib in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1764)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib.<clinit>(videoInputLib.java:81)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561)
    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib$videoInput.<clinit>(videoInputLib.java:193)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.start(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:101)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.start(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:98)
    at quicktest.run(quicktest.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

I already searched and tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061374/opencv-not-working-correctly-on-mac), however this gave me another error:

```
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib$videoInput.<clinit>(videoInputLib.java:193)
at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

does anyone know how to fix this? By the way this happens on a macbook pro 10.7.5 and trying to use the build in webcam. And while it definably shouldn't matter there is also an ocules rift attached. 
Using the `OpenCVFrameGrabber`
gave me a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_highgui in java.library.path` exception instead.

By the way if anyone knows another easy way to get images from my webcam into java that would be helpful to.

Having done what benny.la said I isntead get a

Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnivideoInputLib in java.library.path

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1764)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib.<clinit>(videoInputLib.java:81)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:561)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib$videoInput.<clinit>(videoInputLib.java:193)
at com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.start(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:101)
at com.googlecode.javacv.VideoInputFrameGrabber.start(VideoInputFrameGrabber.java:98)
at quicktest.run(quicktest.java:29)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

exception.

Comment: The error is complaining about missing native library. Similar issue: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=307 . If I understand it correctly, `videoInput` is Windows only. You need to use different library.

Comment: It does not really seem to work even  with the other classes suggested inside your link as it still throws errors, Any other ideas?

Comment: Try using FrameGrabber.createDefault(0)

Comment: Adding that in gives me a null pointer exception I am supposed to change  FrameGrabber grabber = new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0);  into grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0); right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By the way if anyone knows another easy way to get images from my
>   webcam into java that would be helpful to.

Since you're on a macbook, you could do something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencapture tempfile.jpg");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("tempfile.jpg");
```

Comment: This creates a screenshot of the current screen. Not a image from the webcam.

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking that you had the image already on screen.  I noticed in your code, you are calling new VideoInputFrameGrabber(0).  Have you tried calling FrameGrabber.createDefault(0) instead?

Comment: That seems to generate a null pointer exception on the FrameGrabber.createDefault(0) instead

Comment: That sounds odd.  Did you maybe call it as an instance instead of statically (grabber.createDefault instead of FrameGrabber.createDefault).  If not, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: `Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.create(FrameGrabber.java:95)
 at com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.createDefault(FrameGrabber.java:118)
 at quicktest.run(quicktest.java:20)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)`
with line 20 being     `grabber =FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);`

Comment: A NPE there implies an internal call to getDefault() didn't find any available FrameGrabbers.  Did you install javacv or are you just using the jar file?  I believe it needs to be installed to work properly.

Comment: Might be the problem I am just using the jar files as I couldn't really find any good documentations

Comment: I'd start here: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/ and here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your JavaCV isn't set up correctly.

Have you done the following?

1. Downloaded the **xxx-bin.zip** and the **xxx-cppjars.zip** from [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list)
2. Extract the .zip files
3. Add the **xxx-macosx-x86_64.jar** to your eclipse project

Answer (score 1):

The same problem I also faced.
I use mac OSX with OpenCV-2.4.10 with Java CV 0.10

This problem I was getting when I was trying to run ColoredObjectTrack.java(present in javaCV-Samples)
I used OpenCVFrameGrabber instead of VideoInputFrameGrabber. It worked.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? You can add an example code or a quote from the docs.